# How to get date in swift

Tags: swift, date

is there a way to get the date in the format of "May 17, 2019" in swift, currently I have

```
var date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))
var stringDate = "\(date)"
stringDate = String(stringDate.prefix(16))
```

and it has the format of "2019-17-05 1:31" for example

Comment: Use [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) and set the `dateStyle` (not the `dateFormat`).

Comment: Your first line should be: `let date = Date()`.

Comment: Surely you can find your answer in [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+how+to+format+date).

Answer (score -1):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"
        var date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

Comment: I would not advise specifying a literal `dateFormat` when presenting dates in the UI. Use `dateStyle` for localized date strings.

Comment: And once again, `let date = Date()`.